# Page not found is displayed on all my pages - React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have all my routing and as a good practice, i also have my NotFound page, i added this inside my MainLayout, that contains a Navbar and a Footer. But i have a problem, my NotFound page is being displayed with the pages of the other routes.

```
const Root = () => 
  <BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
     <ProtectedRoute exact path="/:username/contact-networks" component={ContactNetworks} /> 
     <ProtectedRoute exact path="/:username/tags" component={UserTags} />
     <ProtectedRoute exact path="/:username/profile-picture" component={UserProfilePicture} />
     <MainLayout nofooter={['/login']}>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        {!isAuthenticated ? (
           <Fragment>
              <Route exact path="/logup" component={Logup} /> 
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
           </Fragment>) : <Redirect to="/" />}
        <Route exact path="/users/:username" component={UserProfile} />
        <Route exact path="/:username/catalog/:product" component={ProductPage} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/:username/products/new" component={PostProduct} />
        <Route exact path="/:username/opinions" component={ClientsOpinions} /> 
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/:username/opinions/new" component={NewOpinion} /> 
        <Route exact path="/:shop/contact" component={ShopContact} />
        <Route exact path="/search/results" component={SearchResults} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
     </MainLayout>
  </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter >
```

This happens:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

All `Route` components need to be a direct child of a `Switch` in order to work properly.  Per [the docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch):

> `<Switch>` is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In contrast, every `<Route>` that matches the location renders inclusively.

What's happening here is that you have `MainLayout` interrupting the parent/child relationship between your `Switch` and your `Route` components.  Therefore the `Route`s resort to their default behavior which is to render all `Route`s that match the path instead of just the first.

You need to introduce an additional `Switch` component inside of `MainLayout` so that the `Routes` have a `Switch` as their parent.  Additionally, you should replace the `Fragment` inside of the `isAuthenticated` branch with a `Switch`.

```
const Root = () => 
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <ProtectedRoute exact path="/:username/contact-networks" component={ContactNetworks} /> 
    <ProtectedRoute exact path="/:username/tags" component={UserTags} />
    <ProtectedRoute exact path="/:username/profile-picture" component={UserProfilePicture} />
    <MainLayout nofooter={['/login']}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        {!isAuthenticated ? (
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/logup" component={Logup} /> 
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            </Switch>) : <Redirect to="/" />}
        <Route exact path="/users/:username" component={UserProfile} />
        <Route exact path="/:username/catalog/:product" component={ProductPage} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/:username/products/new" component={PostProduct} />
        <Route exact path="/:username/opinions" component={ClientsOpinions} /> 
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/:username/opinions/new" component={NewOpinion} /> 
        <Route exact path="/:shop/contact" component={ShopContact} />
        <Route exact path="/search/results" component={SearchResults} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </MainLayout>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter >
```

Comment: Ok I've got to think about this more and check the docs.  It has something to do with the nesting inside `MainLayout`.  If you take that away then the problem goes away.   But obviously you want your layout.

Comment: I think the `Routes` have to be a direct child of a `Switch` rather than a grandchild https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch  "<Switch> is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In contrast, every <Route> that matches the location renders inclusively."

Comment: If you introduce another `Switch` directly inside of the `MainLayout` does that introduce any additional problems, or does that fix it?

Comment: That works but the NotFound route is not working :(

Comment: Ugh I though this would be easy!  Something with the `isAuthenticated` block isn't right.

Comment: Nah, I remove it and the NotFound page is displayed everywhere

Comment: The problem is that the NotFound route doesn't show my NotFoundComponent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227918/discussion-between-linda-paiste-and-gianlop3z).